# Сжимается файл script.js при размещении на хостинге

Tags: javascript, хостинг, минификация

Помогите новичку.
Есть файл main.js который собран из нескольких... на пк  он имеет такой вид:
Размер 12 672, код не сжат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как только перекидываю его на хостинг, он тут же весит меньше, и содержимое урезается, начиная с 160 строки весь код минифицируется в 1 строку (это то место где в файле main.js по сути начинается код из файла script.js). Я не понимаю как так получается и как отменить это сжатие файла (при чем именно куска файла, а не всего целиком.. Я же просто переношу файл из одной папки (которая у меня на пк) в другую папку (которая на хостинге)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос.. получается в проекте есть папка "#source" с исходными файлами, далее это все собирается и перекидывается в файл main.js, который находится в корне проекта, в папке js. И на компе то я вижу, что все собирается верно, этот файл main.js полный, не минифицированный.. затем я просто удаляю все с хостинга, перетаскиваю файлы мои (без папки с исходниками) и файл main.js почем-то меняется.. даже если я отдельно удалю только файл main.js и заменю его, все равно код минифицирован становится

Comment: Хм, сами хостинги себя так не ведут. По идее, единственное что его может минифицировать - это то средство с помощью которого вы перемещаете файл на сервер. попробуйте копировать файлы чем то другим, что бы определить что виновато

Comment: Просто в filezilla перетаскиваю с компа на сервер.. удаляю файл с правой части, затем зажимаю кнопку мыши и тащу слева-направо файл

Comment: Может кодировка символа новой строки скачет?

Comment: Не знаю... просто не так много опыта и пробовал с разных мест файл кидать в проект, один фиг, как только файл попадает на хостинг он ужимается с определенной строки, где импортировался один из файлов, на локальном сервере через f12 все нормально, код не минифицировар...

Comment: Попробуйте файл заархивировать перед передачей на хостинг.